Network Request Failed Android - React Native / Capacitor
I'm having an issue while making a POST request using React Native on an Android 6 simulated device.
It works on recent Android versions though.
The url is a https
usesCleartextTraffic did not work.
This is my fetch:
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      }),
      body: JSON.stringify(request),
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(response => {
        Alert.alert('test', JSON.stringify(response));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was a problem with your fetch operation:', error);
      });

.............................................................................................
